# How to change font color of a specific string in a PDF Document using Java PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have PDF doc. I wanted to change the font color of a specific string (Example : **string1**) using Java PDF Document. All other PDF content, Image,Indentation should remain **unchanged**. All that I need to achieve is to change the font color of 1 and only word. I have to use Apache PDF Box. Please share sample code..

Example :

This is Page 3/3
this application for the purpose of contravention of any Act, Rules, Regulations or any statute of legislation or any notifications/directions issued by any governmental or statutory authority from time to time. I hereby consent to receiving information from Central KYC Registry through SMS/Email on the above registered number/email address.

I/We understand that the NAV applicable to the above transaction will be governed by the applicable SEBI (MF) regulations/Circulars issued by SEBI from time to time.

Your Signature

**signhere1**

Comment: Please share the PDF. There is no easy general solution.

Comment: As @Tilman says, a general solution is beyond the scope of a stack overflow answer. If your cases are simple, though, a special case solution may be feasible.

Comment: Attached the pdf document. The string to be replaced in page 3 - last character signhere1

Comment: I am unable to attach the pdf document. I can send you an email..

Comment: Please share it as a public file share (without spam, so e.g. a public googledrive or dropbox share) and post the link here unless you want to send mails to each and everyone who might be able to help.

Comment: Added the PDF content here...please help

Comment: Added the sample file....

Comment: I'll look tomorrow

Comment: I don't see the link to the sample files.

Comment: The text is "IP Address" and it has to be changed to white colour font.. (this is in page 3)

Comment: That's more difficult because it's in the middle of some text. It's less work to regenerate the PDF by doing copy & paste into word and formatting, then convert to PDF.

Comment: Oh... So pdf to word and then change font colour and then back to pdf again.. All by java..???

Comment: No, just copy and paste. Word can save to PDF.

Comment: If use textstripper all the formatting gets lost. Any other way to change the specific text's font to white in PDF ?

Comment: You would have to mess around with the content stream. To see how difficult this is, have a look at the file with PDFDebugger.